# Speeding up new table entry creation in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have inherited an Access-based CRM. For reasons outside the scope of this question, I need to keep this working for the next 6-12 months until we can replace it with a better solution.

One of the problems that we are facing is the increased time to work with tickets in the CRM. The database is split into a Front-End on our local machines, and a Back-End hosted on a local NAS. This makes it impossible for us to migrate to a MySQL back-end. It is ~300MB in size.

For example, creating a new ticket can take 15-30 seconds before we even see the form. I have a feeling this is due to the Record Source for the form:

`SELECT Tickets.* FROM Tickets ORDER BY Tickets.[Opened Date];`

Other notes that might be useful:

- We need to be able to filter a Ticket and have it populate the current form. Currently this is done in a sub-form on the main Ticket form.
- Copying the Back-End locally (and linking to it) speeds up this process to ~4-5 seconds. Certainly much better, but I feel like we can gain some form of marginal improvement

I have been reading that changes essentially pull down the entire DB, so I'm lost as to how I can improve this process. Also, since I am still relatively new to Access, I may not be including the right information.

How can I improve the speed of this form?

Comment: How many records are in the Tickets table? Could you filter the record source by a currently selected customer?

Comment: About 40,000 records. Would filtering results significantly speed up creation of the table? Currently the process involves filtering after the form is created, which is the current bottleneck. In ~90% of cases, no filtering is done, and it is only done from a sub-form.

Comment: The customer is actually a field linked to another table, along with all other necessary information aside from ticket notes and the like.

Comment: Copy the row source into the query designer SQL view. Play around with criteria in the 'WHERE' clause that meet user requirements and see if you can get the record count down. You're pulling an entire table of data over the network each time you open the form.

Comment: It sounds like I could get by with not running the query at all. But then, how should I ensure that we can continue to filter tickets properly from the sub-form? Does it affect the ability to create the new ticket entry?

Comment: You can make it work with slight adjustments. You can add a combobox to choose Ticket IDs to the main form that filters the subform for you and delete the form's row source. That requires adding a reference to your combobox in the subform's control source. Edit your question to include the control source of your subform and the field names joining the Tickets and Customers tables and I can try to give you an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114395/discussion-between-christopher-d-and-thebluefish).

Comment: It would be better to follow up on Monday once I have a clearer picture of the current setup. Just took off from work, so no longer have it right in front of me =\

Comment: Is `Tickets.[Opened Date]` indexed?

Comment: When you need to add a new record, don't first load 40K rows into your form.